# Making a Multi-line Array in Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to make a multi-line array variable, but it's not working for some reason and I can't work out what I am doing wrong...

The following array works correctly:

```
aInter = Array("Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5")
```

However, when I try and make a multi-line array using the line continuation `& _` it doesn't let me

I've tried various ways:

```
aInter = Array("Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3" & _
"Item 4", "Item 5")

aInter = Array("Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", ) & _
("Item 4", "Item 5")

aInter = Array("Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3") & _
("Item 4", "Item 5")
```

What's the correct way of doing it?

Comment: You'll usually see `& _` together when breaking up strings ` My Name is" & _ " Thomas".   The & is used for the string concatenation and the _  is used to continue your code on the next line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The correct way is:

```
aInter = Array("Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", _
    "Item 4", "Item 5", _
    "Item 6", "Item 7")
```

Comment: I've tried that, Excel says `Compile Error: Expected )` and highlights the first comma.

Comment: What version of MS Excel do you use? I'm using MS Excel 2010 and there's no error.

Comment: You must have a space before the _

Comment: It was indeed a missing space, how silly of me. The array is very big so it's hard to see.

Comment: @Ryflex, there's a limitation... You can join only 25 lines this way (tested on my machine).